# How to close ofstream after assigning to ostream?

Tags: c++, ofstream, ostream

I can do

```
std::ostream& out = condition ? std::cout : std::ofstream(filename);
```

but how do I close in case of `out = std::ofstream(filename)`?

Comment: `of.close()`, or let `of` go out of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood you want to close file stream using `out`?

You don't need to close it explicitly. `std::fstream` is RAII object, so it will close an opened file automatically at the end of enclosing scope.

And of course, you can always cast `out` if you really need to close the file just now:

```
if( ptr = dynamic_cast<std::ofstream*>(out) ) {
    ptr->close();
}
```

Comment: That worked.
I have a base class that holds the ostream and subclasses that provide the actual stream and take care of shutdown

Answer (score 6):

Forget  close for a while, your code:

```
std::ostream& out = condition ? std::cout : of.open(filename);
```

would NOT compile to begin with. `std::ofstream::open()` does NOT return the stream — it returns `void`.  You could fix this as:

```
std::ostream& out = condition ? std::cout : (of.open(filename), of);
```

Now coming back to closing the stream, well, you don't have to, because when the stream object goes out of scope (i.e when the destructor gets called), the destructor will close the file stream. So it is done automatically for you — well, in 99.99% cases, unless you're doing something unusual in which case you want to close it explicitly!

Comment: @downforme: Even that will not compile. Please try to compile your code before posting.

Comment: `std::ostream& out1 = std::cout;
std::ostream& out2 = std::ofstream("");`
does compile

Comment: @downforme: No. `std::ostream& out2 = std::ofstream("");` will not compile in Standard C++. You're probably using MSVC++ (which allows such code)?

Comment: I have VS Express 2013 on Win7 32

Comment: @downforme: See I told you. MSVC++ allows such code, as a compiler extension. This code, however, is not Standard C++.